# The graphical display doesn't agree with the text code in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am reading the code of the Modelica Standard Library. As to the `Modelica.Media.Examples.Utilities.ShortPipe`, I found that the graphical display didn't agree with the text code.

As the following screenshot shows, I am not sure why there is `1e-05` in the graphical dialogue.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is just an bad display when looking at parameters from package-browser in that Dymola version, and it will be corrected later (the 1e-5 actually originates in converting between Pascal and bar, and not incorrectly as I first thought in the start-value in the type).

It does *not* occur when you have dragged in a ShortPipe component to your model (and, of course, you normally should not use that ShortPipe component since it's designed for examples in the media-library).